# get pointer to object which is persitent

Tags: java, pointers, object, linked-list

i have a double linked list with many list elements. so i can use item.next, item.prev and so on... (like item.next.prev.prev.next.prev would also work)
i want to swap two items, so first i need to store the next and prev from item A:

```
Item aprev = a.prev;
Item anext = a.next;
```

now i want to swap b to a:

```
a.next = b.next;
a.prev = b.prev;
a.next.prev = a;
a.prev.next = a;
```

now i need to swap a to b so i use my previous saved Items:

```
b.next = aprev;
b.prev = anext;
...
```

now i got a problem! aprev is a.prev which is now b.prev! so the item loops to his own...

what can i do that i can swap these elements?? I need some kind of temp item but how when the pointer to the object is gone when i overwrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you'll have two swap operations, one for the prev pointers, one for the next pointers:

```
swapPrevPointer(a,b);
swapNextPointer(a,b);
```

with

```
private swapPrevPointer(Item a, Item b) {
   Item temp = a.prev;
   a.prev = b.prev;
   b.prev = temp;
}

private swapNextPointer(Item a, Item b) {
   Item temp = a.next;
   a.next = b.next;
   b.next = temp;
}
```

---

*Visual explanation*

*Initial list:*

```
null <--ap-- A --an--> B --bn--> C 
               <--bp--
```

*After the swap:*

```
null <--ap-- B --an--> A --bn--> C 
               <--bp--
```

*necessary changes*

```
B.prev <- ap ____ swapping "prev" pointers
A.prev <- bp _/
B.next <- an ____ swapping "next" pointers
A.next <- bn _/
```

Comment: Thumbs up for doing it as two discreet operations, because I find it less confusing... because I'm really not very bright ;-) Seriously, six prev's and next's in context AT ONCE baffles me utterly.

Comment: wow thanks, have to try this.. but whats the problem with mine? is it because i make two temp vars?

Comment: @reox - in your last lines it should be: `b.prev = aprev;b.next = anext;`. You strictly have to swap next and prev pointers - no "cross-swapping".

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = a.prev;
a.next = b.next;
a.prev = b;
b.next = a;
b.prev = temp;
```

would do.